# Kubuntu 20.04 power management

Tags: kubuntu, power-management

When i start a video in *Opera* and *VLC* i get the following message : *Opera and 1 other application are currently suppressing power management.*
When i close the video from *Opera* and *VLC* my message remains : *VLC is currently suppressing power management . Playing some media.* , although the video is turned off in *VLC*.
My question is if it affects the battery to discharge more easily because it disables power management ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why the message 'VLC is currently suppressing power management: Playing some media' remains even though VLC is closed?